# Best approach to create time difference variable by id

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas df that looks like this:

```
ID time
34  43
2   99
2   20
34  8
2   90
```

What would be the best approach to a create variable that represents the difference from the most recent time per ID?

```
ID time diff
34  43   35
2   99   9
2   20   NA
34  8    NA
2   90   70
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility

```
df["diff"] = df.sort_values("time").groupby("ID")["time"].diff()
df

    ID  time diff
0   34  43   35.0
1   2   99   9.0
2   2   20   NaN
3   34  8    NaN
4   2   90   70.0
```